# Check width element by JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, submenu

I'm working on menu dropdown by HTML and CSS. I have a issue with checking sub-menu's width.
I have a menu [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8sZF.jpg)

When we point to the element, it will show the dropdown menu [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DRa6.jpg) or [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxn5D.jpg)

The sub-menu is a dynamic menu. It has same style, same css name, but depends on data so that sub menu can be small or large. 
So I would like to check the sub-menu width, if any sub-menu(s) have width larger than 200px -> add one more css class in sub-menu (the others < 200px, must not be added)

My idea is using JS for checking sub-menu element's width. But I'm a newbie on it. I tried with

```
<script>
  if ($('.sub-dropdown').width() > 200) {
       $('.sub-dropdown').addClass('float-right');
  }
</script>
```

But of course, it added to all sub-menu, even they are less than 200px :(

Can anyone have the experience with this issue? Please give me an solution on that.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll tell you why your all sub-dropdown will have class `float-rigth`.
  Only if your one sub-dropdown box's width is bigger then 200, your if judgment will be true ,so the code come in to `$('.sub-dropdown').addClass('float-right');`.this code will add all your box's with class `float-right` which box's class is sub-dropdown.

You should change your code like this

```
$('.sub-dropdown').each(function(index,ele){
    if($(ele).width()>200){
        $(ele).addClass('float-right');
    }
});
```

Comment: OMG. It works! Thank you so much. I learnt one more lesson from you

Comment: Thanks, It's my pleasure to help you